# Positive initial data in a bounded domain forces a solution of a nonlinear heat equation to be positive as well

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded with smooth boundary, and let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ have bounded derivative and satisfy $f(0)=0$. If $u$ solves

\begin{align}
u_t - \Delta u &= f(u) \text{ in } U \times (0,\infty)\\
u(x,t) &= 0 \text{  on } \partial U\times (0,\infty) \\
u(x,0) &= u_0(x)\text{ on } U\times \{t=0\}
\end{align}
where $u_0(x)\ge 0$, then $u\ge 0$ for all $(x,t) \in U\times (0,\infty)$.

I know the result is true (via strong maximum principle) if $f=0$ on $U_T = U\times (0,T)$ for all $T>0$, so I'm wondering if the maximum principle might also help with this problem. If not, them I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the maximum principle, though I'm not sure if the argument is standard. It would go something like this: Suppose first that $f(0)>0$ and $u_0(x) > 0$ for $x \in U$. Then define

$$T = \sup\big\{\tau>0 \, : \, u(x,t)>0 \text{ for all } (x,t) \in U\times [0,\tau)\big\}.$$

By our assumptions $T>0$. We just need to show that $T=\infty$. Assume to the contrary that $T<\infty$. Then $u$ attains its minimum over $U\times [0,T]$ at a point $(x,T)$ where $u(x,T)=0$. Therefore

$$f(0)=u_t(x,T) - \Delta u(x,T)\leq 0.$$

This is a contradiction if $f(0)>0$.

The rest of the proof boils down to reducing the problem to the case where $f(0)>0$ and $u_0>0$. You should try introducing a small parameter $\varepsilon>0$ and making a small perturbation of $u$. For example, $u_\varepsilon(x) = u(x) + \alpha\varepsilon - \varepsilon \exp(\beta x_1)$ should work for appropriately chosen constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: But $f(0)=0$, why are we assuming it's bigger than 0?

Comment: Or perhaps you meant "f(x)>0" in your answer.

Comment: No I do mean $f(0)>0$. The reason is so the inequalities are strict and you get a contradiction. To finish the proof, assume $f(0)=0$ and $u_0\geq 0$, and show that the perturbed function $u_\varepsilon$ is a solution of $u_{\varepsilon,t} - \Delta u_\varepsilon \geq f_\varepsilon(u_\varepsilon)$, where $f_\varepsilon(0)>0$. So the argument above shows that $u_\varepsilon > 0$. Then send $\varepsilon\to 0$. This perturbation trick is very common in maximum principle arguments.